# Reinstalled Windows XP Home, shows as XP Pro, 'invalid' errors

Tags: windows-xp

We reinstalled Windows XP Home after hard drive crash.
The system now shows as XP Pro and we're constantly getting 'invalid software' popups, images show in solid black.
We called Microsoft, they said the serial number is valid etc.
We're assuming that the pop ups are because that it is now XP Pro instead of Home.
Or could it be something else? 
Or how can we determine what the issue is in order to correct it?
Thanks for any advice on this.
jb

Comment: You tried installing XP Home and it installed XP Pro?  Are you using a Microsoft install disk or a 3rd party one?

Comment: It sounds like you did not install with the right media and key. I suggest that you get them, and try again.

Comment: Agree with @KCotreau.  It sounds very much like you installed using and XP Pro disc, but with the XP home key.

Comment: @BBlake They would not have been able to install a legitimate copy of XP Pro with the home key, but it sounds like they used a bogus XP Pro key, or downloaded a hacked copy of Pro with the key/activation included.

Comment: Are the popup we're getting related to the wrong windows version or is it from something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading and burning another retail copy then try reinstalling, if this does not work then you might as well install Ubuntu.

Comment: This computer came from best buy and all software supposedly is kosher.  The disk we used to reinstall came with the computer.  We can try a new install and see.